# CSS not affecting input buttons position/style

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a comment section, and when you click to reply to any comment, a text area and publish/cancel buttons appear under the comment. For some reason though I cannot seem to control the position/style of those buttons.

[I made a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cex3Lkzm/7/) with the exact same code of the comment-section only, and it works like it is supposed to. But once I paste it to my webpage, the buttons position/style changes.

[I also made a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cex3Lkzm/9/) by pasting all of the webpage's content there, and the same problem is there too. You can clearly see the problem when clicking the respond-button on the last comment.

**HTML for the buttons:**

```
<input class="res-com-pub" type="submit" value="Publish">
<input class="res-com-dec" type="submit" value="Cancel">
```

**CSS for the buttons:**

```
.res-com-pub { /*This is the publish button*/
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #336591; /*The button is not even this color*/
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 130px;
}

.res-com-dec { /*This is the cancel button*/
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #878a8c; /*The button is not even this color*/
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 130px;
  top: 130px;
}
```

I have no idea why it isn't working normally. I have classes and CSS that calls those classes. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

remove position: relative and left: 77% from **input[type="submit"]** css rule.

```
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #336591;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* left: 77%; */
}
```

Working JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bx3voh9m/

Comment: The positioning is working fine now, but I still can't change the colors. I modified the JSFiddle and tried to make both buttons red, but the color doesn't change..? https://jsfiddle.net/bcq41ovz/1/

Comment: Color is not changing because your rule is override by other rule so you need to change your rule like this background-color: red !important; 
[Here is working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mbs8jgy/)

Answer (score 0):

First, on `.res-com`, button's parent. Add this `CSS` in order to be similar to the `text field` style:

```
.res-com {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Then, on `input[type=submit]`, add `top: 0` and `right: 0`:

```
input[type=submit] {
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: #336591;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

It should do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just try its working, remove `.res-com-dec,.res-com-pub` on style `top: ***`

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".bottomtext-com").click(function () {
                const container = $(this).parents(".post-container-com");
                const comment = container.siblings(".respond-comment");
                comment.toggle();
            });
        });

        $(".toggle-button").click(function () {
            const $post = $(this).closest('.post-container-com');
            $post.find('.bottomtext-com').toggleClass('bottomtext-small');
            $post.find('.upvote-com').toggleClass('upvote-small');
            $post.find('.downvote-com').toggleClass('downvote-small');
            $post.find('.main-content-com').toggleClass('main-content-small');
            $post.find('.toggle-button').toggleClass('toggle-button-small');
        });
```

```css
   body {
            background-color: #dae0e6;
            color: black;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Roboto;
            margin-top: 70px;
        }

        .topnav {
            position: fixed;
            /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
            top: 0;
            /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
            background-color: white;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #edeff1;
        }

        .topnav img {
            margin-bottom: -5px;
        }

        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .dropdown .dropbtn {
            font-size: 14px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            min-width: 116px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            font-size: 14px;
            float: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .username-btn {
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .dropdown:hover {
            border: 1px solid lightgrey;
            margin: -1px;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .linna-bar {
            margin-top: -25px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #33A8FF;
        }

        .linna-bar p {
            float: left;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 14px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .linna-bar input {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            padding: 12px 30px;
            color: white;
            background-color: #33A8FF;
            /*#33A8FF*/
            border: 1px solid white;
        }

        .post-container {
            background-color: white;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
            width: 75%;
            max-width: 1440px;
            margin-top: 25px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }

        .post-container:hover {
            border: 1px solid #898989;
        }

        /*left side*/

        .left-side {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100px;
            background: #f8f9fa;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        /*main post*/

        .post {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .main-content p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .main-content {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .contain img {
            width: 50%;
        }

        .toptext {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            height: 20px;
            color: #808486;
            font-size: 12px;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .bottomtext {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 5px;
            height: 15px;
            background: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #878a8c;
        }

        .bottomtext img {
            margin-bottom: -2px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .toptext b {
            color: black;
        }

        .title {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .left-side .upvote {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .left-side .downvote {
            padding-top: 7px;
        }

        #logo {
            padding: 0;
            margin-bottom: -5px;
        }

        .newpost {
            margin-bottom: -5px;
        }

        .comments:hover {
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }

        .main-content a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #878a8c;
        }

        .toptext a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        textarea {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 75%;
            height: 100px;
            font-family: inherit;
            max-width: 1440px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        input[type=text],
        textarea {
            border-style: inset;
            border: 1px solid #edeff1;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
            width: 10%;
            min-width: 100px;
            background-color: #336591;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            left: 77%;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: #205681;
        }

        .comments-container {
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            width: 75%;
            background-color: white;
        }

        hr {
            width: 75%;
        }

        /*The comment section starts here*/

        .post-container-com {
            background-color: white;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1440px;
            /*margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;*/
        }


        /*left side*/

        .left-side-com {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 50px;
            min-width: 50px;
            max-width: 50px;
            background: #f8f9fa;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }


        /*main post*/
        .post-com {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .main-content-com p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .main-content-com {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .contain-com img {
            width: 50%;
        }

        .toptext-com {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            height: 20px;
            color: #808486;
            font-size: 12px;
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
        }

        .bottomtext-com {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 5px;
            height: 15px;
            background: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #878a8c;
        }

        .bottomtext-com img {
            margin-bottom: -2px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .toptext-com b {
            color: black;
        }


        .left-side-com .upvote-com {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .left-side-com .downvote-com {
            padding-top: 7px;
        }

        .username {
            color: #2A628F;
        }

        .main-content-small {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-grow: 1;
            display: none;
        }

        .contain-small img {
            width: 50%;
            display: none;
        }

        .bottomtext-small {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 5px;
            height: 15px;
            background: red;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #878a8c;
            display: none;
        }

        .left-side-com .upvote-small {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            display: none;
        }

        .left-side-com .downvote-small {
            padding-top: 7px;
            display: none;
        }


        .toggle-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 8px;
            right: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #2A628F;
            height: 14px;
            width: 20px;
        }

        .toggle-button:hover {
            background-color: #2A628F;
        }

        .toggle-button-small {
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #2A628F;
            height: 20px;
            width: 7px;
        }

        input.toggle-button:focus {
            outline-width: 0;
        }

        .res-com-background {
            height: 170px;
        }

        .comment-reply {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 95%;
            height: 100px;
            font-family: inherit;
            max-width: 1440px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .respond-comment {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-top: 20px;
            position: relative;
            width: 75%;
            display: none;
        }

        .res-com-pub {
            /*This is the publish button*/
            width: 10%;
            min-width: 100px;
            background-color: #336591;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
        }

        .res-com-pub:hover {
            background-color: #205681;
        }

        .res-com-dec {
            /*This is the cancel button*/
            width: 10%;
            min-width: 100px;
            background-color: #878a8c;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            right: 130px;
        }

        .res-com-dec:hover {
            background-color: #7D5B6A;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-container">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div> <img class="upvote" src="https://i.imgur.com/AdwzPRs.png" height="15"> </div>
        <div><b> 1534 </b></div>
        <div> <img class="downvote" src="https://i.imgur.com/XoJ1Jjy.png" height="15"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <p class="toptext">
            <b><a href="lume.php">Test</a></b> · Published by admin 3h ago
        </p>
        <div class="main-content">
            <p class="title">
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
            <p class="contain">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dui libero, blandit non fermentum
                tristique, imperdiet sit amet dolor. Integer interdum massa leo. Donec tempus quam sit amet urna
                bibendum, quis commodo dui laoreet. Ut blandit facilisis dui,
                mollis euismod nunc elementum in. Nam quis ipsum elementum, sagittis arcu quis, pulvinar urna.
            </p>
            <p class="bottomtext">
                <a href="https://google.com">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1IIJe1r.png" height="15">20 comments
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<textarea rows="3" cols="50" placeholder="What are your thoughts?" type="text" id="post-text"
    name="lastname"></textarea>
<form action="action_page.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
<hr>
<div class="comments-container">


    <div>
        <div class="post-container-com">
            <div class="left-side-com">
                <div> <img class="upvote-com" src="https://i.imgur.com/AdwzPRs.png" height="15"> </div>
                <div> <img class="downvote-com" src="https://i.imgur.com/XoJ1Jjy.png" height="15"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-com">
                <p class="toptext-com">
                    <input type="button" class="toggle-button"></input>
                    <span class="username">admin</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;33 points&nbsp;&nbsp;18 minutes ago
                </p>
                <div class="main-content-com">
                    <p class="contain-com">
                        Test post
                    </p>
                    <p class="bottomtext-com">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1IIJe1r.png" height="15">Respond
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="respond-comment">
            <div class="res-com-background">
                <textarea rows="3" cols="50" placeholder="What are your thoughts?" type="text" class="comment-reply"
                    name="comment-reply"></textarea>
                <div class="res-com">
                    <input class="res-com-pub" type="submit" value="Publish">
                    <input class="res-com-dec" type="submit" value="Cancel">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="post-container-com">
            <div class="left-side-com">
                <div> <img class="upvote-com" src="https://i.imgur.com/AdwzPRs.png" height="15"> </div>
                <div> <img class="downvote-com" src="https://i.imgur.com/XoJ1Jjy.png" height="15"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-com">
                <p class="toptext-com">
                    <input type="button" class="toggle-button"></input>
                    <span class="username">admin</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;33 points&nbsp;&nbsp;18 minutes ago
                </p>
                <div class="main-content-com">
                    <p class="contain-com">
                        Test post
                    </p>
                    <p class="bottomtext-com">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1IIJe1r.png" height="15">Respond
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="respond-comment">
            <div class="res-com-background">
                <textarea rows="3" cols="50" placeholder="What are your thoughts?" type="text" class="comment-reply"
                    name="comment-reply"></textarea>
                <div class="res-com">
                    <input class="res-com-pub" type="submit" value="Publish">
                    <input class="res-com-dec" type="submit" value="Cancel">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="post-container-com">
            <div class="left-side-com">
                <div> <img class="upvote-com" src="https://i.imgur.com/AdwzPRs.png" height="15"> </div>
                <div> <img class="downvote-com" src="https://i.imgur.com/XoJ1Jjy.png" height="15"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-com">
                <p class="toptext-com">
                    <input type="button" class="toggle-button"></input>
                    <span class="username">admin</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;33 points&nbsp;&nbsp;18 minutes ago
                </p>
                <div class="main-content-com">
                    <p class="contain-com">
                        Test post
                    </p>
                    <p class="bottomtext-com">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1IIJe1r.png" height="15">Respond
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="respond-comment">
            <div class="res-com-background">
                <textarea rows="3" cols="50" placeholder="What are your thoughts?" type="text" class="comment-reply"
                    name="comment-reply"></textarea>
                <div class="res-com">
                    <input class="res-com-pub" type="submit" value="Publish">
                    <input class="res-com-dec" type="submit" value="Cancel">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a class called "res-com", but it is never declared in your css

```
    <div class="res-com">
      <input class="res-com-pub" type="submit" value="Publish">
      <input class="res-com-dec" type="submit" value="Cancel">
    </div>
```